# Spring ConfigurerAdapter exclude Pattern for separate http method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In SpringBoot application, I have a validator which validates the user for every controller call except admin path patterns

```
    @Configuration
    public class CommsCoreWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(new UserValidator()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/admin/**");
        }

    }
```

The above is working fine, now I want to exclude the user validation for another path say /contents/** but only for HEAD method, I still want the validator to be invoked for GET, POST /contents/**.

Is there a way we can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the validator conditional on the endpoint path **and** the `HttpMethod` you could add conditional logic to the validator. Since you are registering `UserValidator` with the `InterceptorRegistry` then it must be `HandlerInterceptor` so something like this example ...

```
private final AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

public class UserValidator extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        String path = antPathMatcher.extractPathWithinPattern(
            (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE),
            request.getPathInfo()
        );

        if (isExcluded(path, request.getMethod())) {
            // skip the validation
        } else {
           // do whatever your UserValidator usually does
        }

        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    private boolean isExcluded(String path, String requestMethod) {
        boolean isHeadMethod = HttpMethod.HEAD.matches(requestMethod);
        boolean isExcludedPath = EXCLUDED_PATHS.contains(path);
        return isHeadMethod && isExcludedPath;
    }
}
```

.. would allow you to control whether the validation is applied based on both `HttpMethod` and endpoint path.

Comment: Thanks @glitch it does work. I believe this should be added in the framework